# any file format to swf

Tags: flash

Is there any opensource/commercial software that converts ppt, doc, pdf, video, audio into swf format?

Comment: Googling for `ppt to swf` gives 17300000 results in 0.23 seconds. Ain't that enough?

Comment: Thanks Buddy.But I needed one single solution that converts all the formats I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: http://www.swftools.org/ (Open Source)

Makes SWF from PDF, images, video, sound.

To convert from office formats, you will probably need to first convert office files to PDF, and then PDF to SWF. There are many tools to do this, one of the best is OpenOffice in server mode.

An example implementation is Alfresco Share (also Open Source), which uses swftools and OpenOffice to convert all sorts of files to SWF.

Comment: FYI, Alfresco uses JODConverter to convert office files to PDF. So you can use JODConverter+SWFTOOLS to reach your goal.